# Java 9 migration on intellij issues with module system

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9

I am try to migrate my current project to be able to compile and run it on java 9. I am trying first to just move a java8 based project to java9 without not much effort which means not moving to jigsaw basically.

The project structure is something like

```
myjava-service [myjava-service-parent] parent-pom with the following modules
 - myjava-service 
 - myjava-service-common
 - myjava-service-test
```

it compiles perfectly with mvn clean package and it runs when I execute that fat.jar

the nightmare starts when I try to run it using intellij,to run on intellij i have to set the module I want to execute which is myjava-service  but then apparently intellij understand it as java 9 module and well a lot of split packages issues, classes not found and other issues that I am struggling to fix, so my question is there a way to run the service on intellij under the java 9 environment without the new java module system being triggered somehow?

for the record issues like

`java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules javax.annotation.api and annotations export package javax.annotation to module javax.el`

Comment: The question is either too vague or too broad. Can you be specific on the exact errors that your IDE is reporting? Also, is intellij being run on java 9?

Comment: hey yes I can as I said, split package issues with many libraries, it's just one of the issues, but yes I can give you, I will update my question with some of the errors, but please I don't expect patch comands to fix this, I've been patching many libraries already :(

Comment: I just read my question and I see what you mean it looks like I want to fix all the issues, but actually I just would like to run my project on intellij without the java module system being activated, maybe it sound better now?

Comment: Do you have to run on Java 9, though?

Comment: Yes, we really would like to have a idea of how much effort is to migrate a service to java 9, we don't wanna be way behind in java versions. and we would like to do it gracefully, first put this service up and running with minimal effort in the begging and then slowly add java 9 features and etc...

Comment: Did you try and [go the Oracle way](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-7744EF96-5899-4FB2-B34E-86D49B2E89B6) while migrating?

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently someone stepped into the same issue that I was facing, so what happens is that when your service start by a class which is not part of your sources (in my case my service is started by Starter class from the Vertx jar) then IDEA end up using the module path instead of class path. luckily Intellij team was quite helpful, follow up the ticket

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-187390 , ***for the next version IDEA will abstain from using module path when there is no module-info file in sources.***

Also for those who need desperately run a service in java 9 there's a work around which is basically create a Main class and Invoke it inside the class that starts your service, in my Case it looked like

```
public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Starter.main(args);
    }
}
```